# Cannot prove these two limit statements about Bernoulli sequence (tail probabilities)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

In the 8th chapter of *An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications. Vol 1* (by William Feller) there are two problems that I'm stuck with, and since the two are interconnected, I decided to ask a question about them at one place.
The problems 7 and 8 (both about unending Bernouli sequance) of the aforementioned chapter are as follows:

> 7. Let the *$\phi$(t)* be a positive monotonically increasing function, and let *$n_r$* be the nearest integer to *$e^{r/log\,r}$*. If *$$\sum {\frac{1}{\phi(n_r)}}{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2(n_r)}}\qquad\qquad(1)$$* converges, then with probability one, the inequality *$$S_n>np\,+\sqrt{npq}\,\,\phi(n)\qquad\qquad(2)$$* takes place for finitely many *n*. Note that without loss of generality we may suppose that *$\phi(n)\,<10\sqrt{log\,log\,n}$*; the law of the iterated logarithm takes care of the larger *$\phi(n)$*.
> 8. Prove that the series (1) converges if, and only if,*$$\sum\frac{\phi(n)}{n} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2(n) }\qquad\qquad(3)$$* converges. *Hint:*  Collect the terms for which *$n_{r-1}\,<\,\,n\,\,<n_r$* and note that *$n_r \,- n_{r-1} \sim n_r(1-1/log\,r) $*; furthermore, (3) can converge only if *$\phi^2(n)\,\,>\,2\,log\,log\,n$*.

[Before going into the challenges that I faced, I should tell you that I am not familiar with measure theory and in the first volume of this book everything is proved and demonstrated without use of it. So I suppose it is possible to solve the problems without measure theory.]

For the problem 7, if we define the sequence of events {$A_r$}s such that the inequality *$$S_{n_r}>n_rp\,+\sqrt{n_rpq}\,\,\phi(n_r)$$* holds, and if we assume *$\phi(n)$* is adequately small so that normal approximation still applies, say *$\phi(n)\,=\,O(\sqrt[7]n)$*, we can use the approximation of CDF of normal distribution for large values of x ([see here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistributionFunction.html)), that is: *$$\int_x^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,\simeq\,\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$* Now we know the probability assigned to each *{$A_r$}* for sufficiently large *r* is the summand of (1) times *$1/\sqrt{2\pi}$*. As a result we are in a position to apply the first Borel-Cantelli lemma and conclude *{$A_r$}* s will happen only finitely. But the problem is we only proved the statement for *n*s of the kind *$e^{r/log\,r}$*, nothing was said about other *n*s and the problem is still unsolved. The "*Note*" which was written at the end of the problem, too, does not help much. It can only help for the set of $\phi(n)$s that satisfy *$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{\sqrt{2\,log\,log\,n}}\,=\,\lambda\,>\,1$*. It is ineffective with $\phi(n)$s of the kind: *$$\phi(n) =\,(1+\epsilon(n))\, \sqrt{2\,log\,log\,n}$$* in which epsilone tends to zero as n tends to infinity (It does not work on finer forms of the law of the iterated logarithm).

For the problem 8, it seems there is a typo in the *hint*; the approximation should be: *$n_r\,-n_{r-1}\,\sim\,\frac{n_r}{log\,(r-1)}\,\sim\frac{n_r}{log\,r}$*. Again, I'm stuck and cannot demonstrate how the two series are related. Even the hint is not helpful to me, I can't relate the summation of terms for *n*s between *$n_{r-1}$* and *$n_r$* to the summation (1).

Thank you all.